# Paypal - allowing customer to enter value on buy now button

Tags: paypal

My question is this - is there any way to create a paypal button which allows the customer to enter the value of the amount they wish to pay. I do not wish to use a 'donate' button because it is not a donation situation - it is a sale of a product.

Example: I have an ethically produced environmentally friendly product. The base price will be $10.00 (for example), but I would ask and allow people to pay/contribute more if they wanted to in support of the ethical/environmental aspect of the product.

So one customer might want to pay $11 while another might want to pay $13.

Is it possible to allow this to happen with any type of paypal button - excluding the donate button.

Thanks

R

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is possible, but what you'd need to do is have a system by which they would enter their price on your website (and obviously you can check it's >=$10) and once they've entered a price, you would create the [button code](https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_pdn_xclick_techview_outside) using the price they've specified.